# Update values in pandas columns based on values from another DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe

Two DataFrames `df1` and `df2` both has Weight in lb columns
if Weight in lb matches I need to update the corresponding BMI in df1 from df2.

DataFrame
`df1`=

| Index | First Name | Age | Gender | Weight in lb | BMI |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | James | 21 | Male | 167 |  |
| 1 | John | 25 | Male | 175 |  |
| 2 | Patricia | 23 | Female | 132 |  |
| 4 | Kevin | 22 | Male | 169 |  |
| 5 | Alex | 27 | Male | 169 |  |

DataFrame
`df2`=

| Weight in lb | BMI | Height |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 165 | 16.5 | 180 |
| 166 | 17.0 | 180 |
| 167 | 17.3 | 180 |
| 168 | 17.4 | 180 |
| 169 | 17.9 | 180 |
| 170 | 18.4 | 180 |
| 171 | 18.7 | 180 |
| 172 | 18.9 | 180 |
| 173 | 19.2 | 180 |
| 174 | 19.3 | 180 |
| 175 | 19.6 | 180 |
| 176 | 19.9 | 180 |
| 177 | 20.0 | 180 |
| 178 | 20.2 | 180 |
| 179 | 21.6 | 180 |
| 180 | 21.9 | 180 |
| 181 | 22.1 | 180 |
| 182 | 22.3 | 180 |
| 183 | 22.5 | 180 |
| 184 | 22.8 | 180 |
| 185 | 22.9 | 180 |
| 186 | 23.0 | 180 |
| 187 | 22.1 | 180 |
| 188 | 22.1 | 180 |

I tried

```
df1['BMI'] = df2.loc[df2['Weight in lb'].isin(df1['Weight in lb'],'BMI']
```

But it is not working, I cannot do merge operation because the original dataframe is too complex for that

Desired Output
`df1`=

| Index | First Name | Age | Gender | Weight in lb | BMI |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | James | 21 | Male | 167 | 17.3 |
| 1 | John | 25 | Male | 175 | 19.6 |
| 2 | Patricia | 23 | Female | 132 |  |
| 4 | Kevin | 22 | Male | 169 | 17.9 |
| 5 | Alex | 27 | Male | 169 | 17.9 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use df2 to make a mapping from weight to BMI and then use it on df1

```
weight_to_bmi = dict(df2.values)
df1['BMI'] = df1['Weight in lb'].map(weight_to_bmi)
```

Comment: The answer works but my original dataframe df2 has one more column height, which I didn't show here for simplicity I will edit the question to include that too.

Then the solution would be 




weight_to_bmi = pd.Series(df2['Weight in lb].values,index=df2['BMI']).to_dict()

df1['BMI'] = df1['Weight in lb'].map(weight_to_bmi)

Answer (score 1):

Building off of mitoRibo's Answer

```
weight_to_bmi = pd.Series(df2['Weight in lb'].values,index=df2['BMI']).to_dict()
df1['BMI'] = df1['Weight in lb'].map(weight_to_bmi)
```

Comment: you can also do `dict(df2[['Weight in lb','BMI']])`